# exploding json then dataframe.select all the keyvalues into columns

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm exploding some JSON from a big return and instead of having to specify each individual column I wish to select into the dataframe I wish to do a "select all" so that everything that is a string for example just goes into a dataframe as a column.

An example would be:

```
df = df.select(col('d.__next').alias("nexttoken"), explode(col('d.results')).alias("result"))
df = df.select(explode(df.result.jobInfoNav.results).alias("jobInfoNav"))
df = df.select(df.jobInfoNav, df.jobInfoNav.positionNav)
```

but instead of

```
df = df.select(df.jobInfoNav.jobCode.alias("JobCode"),df.jobInfoNav.position.alias("PositionCode"),df.jobInfoNav.jobTitle.alias("JobTitle"), df.jobInfoNav.positionNav.targetFTE.alias("TargetFTE"), df.jobInfoNav.lastModifiedDateTime.alias("lastModifiedDateTime"))
```

Afterwards to get particular columns could I do something similar to say

```
df = df.select(df.jobInfoNav.*)
```

**UPDATE**

Schema:

```
root
 |-- jobInfoNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- __metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attachment: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attachmentFileName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attachmentFileSize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attachmentFileType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attachmentId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attachmentMimeType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attachmentStatus: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- businessUnit: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- businessUnitNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- company: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- companyNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- contractEndDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- contractType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- contractTypeNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- costCenter: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- costCenterNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- createdBy: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- createdDateTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- createdOn: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customDate1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customDouble1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customDouble2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString10: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString11: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString11Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString12: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString13: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString13Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString14: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString14Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString15: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString15Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString16: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString16Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString17: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString17Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString18: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString1Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString21: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString22: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString23: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString24: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString25: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString26: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString27: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString2Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString3Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString4: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString4Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString5: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString5Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString6: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString6Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString7: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString7Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString8: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString8Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString9: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customString9Nav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- defaultOvertimeCompensationVariant: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- department: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- departmentNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- division: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- divisionNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- effectiveLatestChange: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- emplStatus: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- emplStatusNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- employeeClass: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- employeeClassNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- employmentNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- endDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- event: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- eventNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- eventReason: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- eventReasonNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fte: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- holidayCalendarCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- holidayCalendarCodeNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- jobCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- jobCodeNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- jobTitle: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastModifiedBy: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastModifiedDateTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastModifiedOn: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- locationNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- managerEmploymentNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- managerId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- managerUserNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- payGrade: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- payGradeNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- position: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- positionEntryDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- positionNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- businessUnit: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- businessUnitNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- changeReason: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- changeReasonNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- comment: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- company: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- companyNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- costCenter: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- costCenterNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- createdBy: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- createdByNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- createdDateTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- creationSource: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- creationSourceNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- criticality: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_AE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_AEName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_AENav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_AM: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_AMName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_AMNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_COC: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_COCNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_DIOH: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_DIOHNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_buGroup: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_buGroupNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_contractType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_contractTypeNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_costObjectType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_costObjectTypeNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_employeeLevel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_makro: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_makroNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_nameEN: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_nameTH: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_parentPositionUser: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_parentPositionUserNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_province: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_provinceNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_region: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_regionNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_serviceType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_site: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_siteNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_team: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cust_teamNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- department: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- departmentNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- division: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- divisionNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- effectiveEndDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- effectiveStartDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- effectiveStatus: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- effectiveStatusNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- employeeClass: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- employeeClassNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- externalNameTranslationTextNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- externalName_defaultValue: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- externalName_en_DEBUG: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- externalName_en_GB: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- externalName_en_US: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- externalName_localized: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- externalName_th_TH: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- incumbent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- incumbentNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- jobCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- jobCodeNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- jobLevel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- jobLevelNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- jobTitle: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lastModifiedBy: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lastModifiedByNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lastModifiedDateTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- legacyPositionId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- locationNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- mdfSystemOptimisticLockUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- mdfSystemRecordStatus: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- mdfSystemRecordStatusNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- multipleIncumbentsAllowed: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- parentPosition: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- payGrade: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- payGradeNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- payRange: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- payRangeNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- positionControlled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- positionCriticality: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- positionCriticalityNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- positionMatrixRelationship: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- positionTitle: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- regularTemporary: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- regularTemporaryNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rightToReturn: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- standardHours: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- targetFTE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- technicalParameters: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- transactionSequence: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- vacant: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- wfRequestNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- probationPeriodEndDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- seqNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- startDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timeRecordingAdmissibilityCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timeRecordingProfileCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timeRecordingVariant: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timeTypeProfileCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timeTypeProfileCodeNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timezone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- userId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- userNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- wfRequestNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- workscheduleCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- workscheduleCodeNav: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- __deferred: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
```

**UPDATE 2**

I was close I had to wrap the statement in quotes.

```
df = df.select("jobInfoNav.*")
```

Cheers

Comment: If after explode you are getting jobInfoNav as struct type you can do df.jobInfoNav.* in select

Comment: @AnjaneyaTripathi tried that doesn't work.